# Add array to session Symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, session

I try to add array of multiple vals to session var bu sending ajax request. I do this:

```
public function addFoodAction(Request $request)
{
    $foodId = json_decode($request->getContent(), true)['food'];
    $food = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('HackatonDinningRoomBundle:Food')->find($foodId);
    $arr = array();
    $arr[]=$food;
    $session = $this->get('session');
    $session->set('items', array($food));

    return new Response(count($arr));
}
```

How I can do that ?

Comment: I see some issues with your code but what are you expecting and what are you actually receiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `serialize`:

```
$session->set('items', serialize(array($food)));
```

To retrieve the data:

```
unserialize($session->get('items'));
```

Comment: In addition to what @Gnucki said, I'd recommend using something other than the default serializer in php. Things like circular references can cause your program to crash. I'd recommend jms/serializer (but symfony/serializer works also).

Comment: echochamber is right, you should take a look at [JMSSerializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) if the serialized object is a bit complicated.